# Spring request validation

Tags: spring, rest

I discover that *Spring* request validation differs from *laravel-validation*. 
I must validate fields by type and by other constraints (e.g. max length). But *Spring* throws different exceptions when field cannot be casted to Dto’s field type (thrown by *Jackson*) or it’s just too long (thrown by *jsr-303*).

How can I validate JSON request by JSON-schema? I think it’s better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use javax.validation.constraints on your DTOs. Here is an example from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @AssertTrue
    private boolean working;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
      = "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    private String aboutMe;

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    // standard setters and getters 
}
```

Comment: Suppose that user sends JSON like {“email”: [1,2]}. How will jsr-303 handle it?

Comment: This code doesn’t validate JSON but result domain object

Comment: It will be mapped to your DTO which will be annotated with say @email. Validating JSON inside Spring without an Object, I am not sure but will do some research on it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I deal with the problem using java-json-tools/JSON-Schema-Validator library. 
I have created service with only one method: “validate” which receives JsonNode and name of file with json-schema. If validation fails, validator throws my custom exception, and exception handler renders error message